# Twig template can not access js method

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony, twig

well I have a problem with using global js variables in render template.

Here is the code.

I have single-product.html.twig page which extend base.html.twig.
Base.html.twig contain all my js and css files,
single-product.html.twig and category.html.twig, both of this pages render controller with the template.

```
single-product.html.twig
{% render( controller('SiteBundle:Default:renderApointmentSection')) %}
```

In the template, I have two dropdowns. The second drop down would be filled on change from first one.

```
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="select-field">
        <select name="brand" class="selectpicker" onchange="models.getCarModels(this)" data-placeholder="Marka...">
          {% for b in brandDropDown %}
             <option value="{{ b.id }}">{{ b.name }}</option>
          {% endfor %}
        </select>
      <div class="icon-holder">
        <span class="flaticon-sign"></span>
      </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
     <div class="select-field">
        <select name="model" id="models" class="selectpicker" data-placeholder="Model..."></select>
     <div class="icon-holder">
       <span class="flaticon-transport"></span>
     </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

In base.html.twig I have custom.js i models.js. models.js is service and has object modelService, which have some functions inside.
I custom.js, there is global property `models = new ModelsService();`

Everything works fine, but when I change first drop down, I get an error

> Uncaught TypeError: models.getCarModels is not a function(…)

```
models.js
var ModelsService = function()
{
    /**
     * Get Models by BrandId
     */
    this.getCarModels = function(self)
    {
        if($(self).val().length && $(self).val() > 0){
        var brandId = $(self).val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: API_URL +"/get-models-by-brand/"+ brandId,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: onGetModels,
                error: function(error){
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
        }
    };
  };
```

When I call this method from single-product.html.twig it works fine, only from render template with the controller I got this error.

Also, I notice, while page loads js populate some other parts in this template. 
I created preselected option for select boxes and select boxes from this template were filled also with this option.
That method called on document ready.

Comment: Check is the js file included in your phtml file .?

Comment: It is included in base.html.twig.
single-product.html has

{% extends('@Site/base.html.twig') %} - on first line
{% render( controller('SiteBundle:Default:renderApointmentSection')) %} - on last line
When open console ther is models.js and custom.js files